# How to extend Highcharts plotline past the plot area

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

With these basic options, this chart is feeling cramped — the 'U.S. Average' plotline label is overlapping the first bar.

Is there a way to add padding to the top and bottom of the plot area, thereby giving a little breathing room for the plotline & its label?

[JSFiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jacobpatton/4v133hnm/36/)

Plotline code:

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  chart: {
    style: {
      fontFamily: "Oswald, sans-serif",
      textTransform: "uppercase"
    }
  }
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "chart": {
    "renderTo": "container",
    "type": "bar"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Percent of Adults Who Binge Drank"
  },
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "2013 | Percent of Adults Who Binge Drank"
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["Boston", "Denver", "Miami", "New York", "Phoenix", "San Antonio", "San Jose", "Seattle", "Washington"],
    "labels": {
      "useHTML": true,
      "style": {
        "width": "100px",
        "min-width": "100px",
        "text-align": "right"
      }
    }
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": null
    },
    "plotLines": [{
      "color": "#9b9b9b",
      "dashStyle": "shortdot",
      "value": 26,
      "width": 2,
      "label": {
        "text": "U.S. Average",
        "align": "left",
        "x": 5,
        "rotation": 0,
        "zIndex": 1000,
        "useHTML": true,
        "style": {
          "font-size": "10px",
          "background-color": "#fff"
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  "series": [{
    "data": [35, 26, 18, 18, 15, 21, 55, 19, 22],
    "color": "#e12922"
  }],
  "exporting": {
    "enabled": true,
    "buttons": {
      "contextButton": {
        "menuItems": "buttons"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height:400px;width:600px;margin:1.5em 1em;"></div>
```

Comment: This might help it's about rendering the text with css http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/renderer-text-on-chart/ which links from here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.css

Comment: Couldn't you just move your label a little bit higher using y parameter of your label? http://jsfiddle.net/4v133hnm/37/ You can use wrapper I have written some time ago for changing width and height of your plotArea:
http://jsfiddle.net/4v133hnm/38/